# BodyParser sends undefined when reading form

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I'm building a site using node.js and express, so, in order to read signup information (username, password and email), I'm using BodyParser.

This is the jade code where the form is included. It is inside my 'views' folder.

```
form(class="form" method="post" action="/UsuarioReg" enctype="multipart/form-data")
                    label(class="col-lg-12") username
                    input(type="text" name="username")
                    br
                    label(class="col-lg-12") password
                    input(type="password" name="password")
                    br
                    label(class="col-lg-12") email
                    input(type="email" name="email")
                    br
                    input(type="submit" value="Signup")
```

This is my 'server.js' file, which is located in the root folder.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false} ));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'anyString',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
require('./app/routes.js')(app);
```

And finally, this is my 'routes.js' file, which is inside the 'app' folder.

```
var User = require('./models/user');

module.exports = function (app){
app.post('/UsuarioReg' ,function(req,res){

        var newUser = new User();
        newUser.local.username = req.body.username;
        newUser.local.password = req.body.password;
        newUser.local.email = req.body.email;
        console.log('Data received: \nusername: ' + newUser.local.username + '\npassword: ' + newUser.local.password + '\nemail: ' + newUser.local.email); 

        newUser.save(function (err) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
        });

        res.send('Successful signup');    
    });
};
```

However every time I send a sign up form, bodyparser shows 'undefined'. I'm sure the action '/UsuarioReg' has the same name in both the jade and the routes.js files, is there any piece of code I'm missing, or maybe an incorrect order of the variable declarations inside the 'server.js' file?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from your form if you're not uploading any files. The bodyparser middleware cannot parse multipart form data. If you want to upload files you're going to need another middleware like multer.